# Error getting the property 'rows' in a gridview

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

I am getting error in the code which is shown in the comment(Please read it carefully)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery- 2.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var grid = document.getElementById("<%=gvCustomers.ClientID%>");//gvCustomers is the ID of a gridview
       val();     
    function val() {
        if (grid.rows.length > 0) {//Unable to get property 'rows' of null or 'undefined' value
            alert(grid.rows.length);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Where am I going wrong ? Even i don't have an empty gridview!

THE HTML CODE IS ALSO HERE:

```
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
<asp:GridView ID="gvCustomers" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty ="true"
    DataKeyNames="CustomerID" OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID ="btn" Text ="+" runat="server" />
                <asp:Panel ID="pnlOrders" runat="server" Style="display: none">
                    <asp:GridView ID="gvOrders" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass = "ChildGrid">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="OrderId" HeaderText="Order Id" />
                            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="OrderDate" HeaderText="Date" />
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                </asp:Panel>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="ContactName" HeaderText="Contact Name" />
        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
        </div>
</form>
```

Comment: First you call your function before init the grid object...

Comment: oh i got it let me try this

Comment: Can you add the html code of your gridview ?

Comment: see the html code...and see where i am going wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not selecting right the gridview.

Try this

```
var grid = document.getElementById("gvCustomers");
```

**UPDATE**

Using Jquery, try this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var grid = document.getElementById("gvCustomers");
    function val() {
        if (grid.rows.length > 0) {//Unable to get property 'rows' of null or 'undefined' value
            alert(grid.rows.length);
        }
    }
  val();
});
```

Comment: even i tried this...not working  let me tell you that '<%='ID'.ClientID%>' is same as <"ID">...when it runs... '<%='ID'.ClientID%>' becomes <"ID"> in source code

Comment: your script is at the end of your html ?

Comment: Jquery to get the id of gridview ? .As i called in javascript!

Comment: No for make sure your document is ready before execture the script. Look at my update.

Comment: thanks....it worked it out!!! but i am unable to reputate you because i need 15 reputation for this